# Facebook API Send Message : How to send link

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I send messages with facebook application, the messages are texts

I want to send link in the message.

This is my code :

```
$message_to_reply = '<a href="http://test.com">hello</a>';


$ch = curl_init($url);
$jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
        "id":"' . $sender . '"
    },
    "message":{
        "text":"' . $message_to_reply . '"
    }
}';

$jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: You can not send your own custom HTML. You can only put your URL inside the message text, and let messenger parse it and make it into a link automatically.

Comment: is there a way to do a <br/>  or \n in the text ?

Comment: i tried \n  it not work

Comment: I guess \n would work, if you prepared the appropriate data structure and then encoded it as JSON, instead of creating JSON “manually”.

Comment: i tried, i got that error
{"error":{"message":"(#10) This message is sent outside of allowed window. You need page_messaging_subscriptions permission to be able to do it. Learn more about the new policy here: https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/messenger-platform\/policy-overview","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":2018065,"fbtrace_id":"AUTlC9aKRBJ"}}

Comment: That simply means that it was too late to send the message by then, because the last time the user messaged your bot first was too long ago. Has nothing whatsoever to do with line breaks.